# nginx Expires header and reverse proxy not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, expires-header

I am trying to configure an Expires header for static files on nginx (0.7.67). The static files are served from a Golang reverse proxy:

```
location /rev/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8910/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;

  # I am putting this here, because nginx only uses one location. Is this OK?
  location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
    expires 30d;
  }
}
```

When I do it this way there is no error restarting nginx, but the static files are not served anymore.

I **already tried** the following constellation, but it's not working:

```
server {
  ...
  location /rev/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8910/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
      expires 30d;
  }
}
```

**Question**: How can I apply an expires header for static files which are located on an application behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: I wonder why this is not on serverfault?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way i have managed to accomplish it was this way:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
}

# CACHING WITH NO LOGGING
location ~* ^.+\.(atom|bmp|bz2|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|mid|midi|mp4|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rss|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tgz|ttf|txt|wav|woff|xls|zip)$ {
    access_log  off;
    log_not_found   off;
    expires     max;
    proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
}

# CACHING WITH 404 LOGGING
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|xml)$ {
    access_log  off;
    log_not_found   on;
    expires     max;
    proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And I set proxy settings in server{} block.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the docs at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule I find mentions of using the `proxy_cache_*` directives to achieve similar functionality, although not exactly what you're after. The docs state that:

```
Upstream cache-related directives have priority over proxy_cache_valid value,
in particular the order is:

X-Accel-Expires
Expires/Cache-Control
proxy_cache_valid
```

So it seems that setting the `Expires` header at the proxy level may not be supported, or recommended.

I have a feeling that you should be setting the `Expires` header up-stream. This can be done in Go (slightly hackishly, I'm sure there's a nicer way to fix the time-zone in the string) by setting the header on the http.ResponseWriter in your http handler function:

```
w.Header().Set("Expires", strings.Replace(time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 30).Format(time.RFC1123), "UTC", "GMT", 1))
```

As previously stated, this replaces `UTC` with `GMT` in the output string. I'm not sure if it's necessary, but I've noticed this seems to be the common form in any HTTP headers I've inspected. I haven't looked up the spec to see if `UTC` would be equally accepted by browsers, but I don't see why not.

Sorry it's not really an Nginx answer, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `expires` directive or `add_header` is what you return to the browser.

If you blindly want to cache what comes from the backend, you can try:

```
proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid